# Send mail from non default account which is not in the sessions accounts

Tags: email, outlook, vsto

I have created the following...

```cs
Outlook.MailItem oMail;
oMail = Inspector.CurrentItem;
Outlook.NameSpace session = oMail.Session;
Outlook.Accounts accounts = session.Accounts;
```

When looping through accounts, I get the accounts which has been added physically in Outlook, but not the ones added through the “*Open these addition mailboxes*” in **Account Settings -> Change -> More Settings -> Advanced**

How can I access those and get the account information from that so I can use it in my, `oMail.SendUsingAccount = account`

Comment: You should include what version of Outlook you are using

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Outlook 2007+, the code below will provide you with the delegate Exchange mailboxes a given user has access to (*the "Open these additional mailboxes" listing*). The key ingredient is the Session data [`Stores`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb176787%28v=office.12%29.aspx) and the [`ExchangeStoreType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb208080%28v=office.12%29.aspx).

```cs
foreach (var store in Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Session.Stores.Cast<Outlook.Store>().Where(c=>c.ExchangeStoreType == Outlook.OlExchangeStoreType.olExchangeMailbox)) 
            Trace.WriteLine(store.DisplayName);
```

To send a message on behalf of another mailbox, you should use the property [`MailItem.SendOnBehalfName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook._mailitem.sentonbehalfofname.aspx) - since you technically only have one account ([*see this Outlook forums post*](http://www.outlookforums.com/archive/index.php/t-15476.html)).