# How do I create an Outlook Task to a specific mailbox using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, outlook, activex, ms-office, ole

I am attempting to automate the creation of an Outlook Task using JavaScript in a local IE-only environment (using Outlook 2007/2010). I have been able to do so using an Outlook ActiveX object, with one minor catch, my method creates the task in the user's default mailbox. (The 9 in the code below is the enumerated constant for the task folder)

What I need to do is create the task in a separate shared mailbox. I am looking for a way to set the task to the specific shared mailbox (that the user has access to) by name rather than the user's personal (default) folder.  What I have so far is below.

```
     function createTask() {
               //create Outlook object and map to the task folder
                var outlookApp = new ActiveXObject("Outlook.Application");
                var nameSpace = outlookApp.getNameSpace("MAPI");
                var mailFolder = nameSpace.getDefaultFolder(9); //olFolderTask

               //create the task
               var task = mailFolder.Items.add('IPM.Task');
                //set task properties 
                task.Subject = 'Subject';
                task.Body = "Body of Task";          
                task.StartDate = "01/01/2012";
                task.DueDate = "06/01/2012";
                task.ReminderSet = true;
                task.Save();
      }
```

I have found some potentially useful information [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff861238.aspx), with an alternate to the getDefaultFolder function in GetFolderFromID, but I have not been able to find a way using JavaScript/ActiveX to get the needed EntryID just from the Shared Mailbox's name.

I am new to working with Outlook, any suggestions or guidance would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the [`Session.Stores`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff864790.aspx) as discussed in [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9231786/175679). It contains all the  available mailbox stores ([*`Store`*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff862128.aspx)) a user has in their profile.

Once you've identified the `Store` you're after, you can use [`Store.GetDefaultFolder`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff869924.aspx) to retrieve the shared mailbox task [`Folder`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff863890.aspx) you are interested in.

Comment: Thank you very much! This is exactly what I needed. For what it's worth, I wasn't able to use [Store.GetDefaultFolder] (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff869924.aspx) with Outlook 2007, but was able to use [Store.GetRootFolder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff860733.aspx) to get the job done for both environments.