# How to capture sent items with Outlook addin across multiple accounts?

Tags: c#, outlook, add-in

I have built an Outlook 2010 Addin using C#. I created an Inspector wrapper and I am using it to capture when an item is added to the Sent Items folder.

I then capture some details about that item and do something with it.

It's been working great, but I've recently come across someone who has multiple email accounts in Outlook. My addin seems only to capture the items from 1 of the sent item folders.

```
sentfolder = this.Application.Session.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderSentMail);
sentitems = sentfolder.Items;
sentitems.ItemAdd += new Outlook.ItemsEvents_ItemAddEventHandler(sentitems_ItemAdd);

_wrappedInspectors = new Dictionary<Guid, InspectorWrapper>();
_inspectors = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Inspectors;
_inspectors.NewInspector += new Outlook.InspectorsEvents_NewInspectorEventHandler(WrapInspector);
```

Obviously I just need to iterate through the folders for the different accounts and identify each of the sent items folders but I am unsure how to achieve that.

Answer (score 0):

If the user has multiple email accounts, the [`Session.Stores`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb176787%28v=office.12%29.aspx) or `Session.Accounts` should provide access to the other shared mailboxes they use.

See this [related SO post on how to get access to shared mailboxes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9231786/175679).