# Read and Restore additional mailboxes list using C# in Outlook

Tags: c#, api, outlook

Is it possible to read "additional mailboxes" list using C# Outlook API?

The list is placed in following window in outlook:

Tools > Account Settings > Email > Select Account > Change... > 
On the 'Microsoft Exchange Server Settings' tab, select 'More Settings ...'
On the 'Microsoft Exchange Server', add the additional mailbox select the 'Advanced' tab.
Here in this tab, all additional mailboxes are listed in a listbox under 'Open these additional mailboxes' label.

I have to to backup and restore this list using C# Code.

Can I do that using Outlook Interop libraries?

Thanks in advance for your answers.

Answer (score 1):

I found the way to read all mailboxes:
Here is the code example:

```
using System;
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var oApp = new Application();

        var oNS = oApp.GetNamespace("MAPI");

        Stores stores = oNS.Stores;

        foreach (Store store in stores)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Name: {0} \n Path: {1} \n Type: {2} \n IsDataFileStore: {3}", 
                                store.DisplayName, store.FilePath, store.ExchangeStoreType, store.IsDataFileStore);

            Console.WriteLine(Environment.NewLine);
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Done");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

The new question is how can I restore those mailbox using C#? :)

Answer (score 0):

You can access additional shared mailboxes by using [`Session.Stores`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff864790.aspx) (*Outlook Interop*). See this [related SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9231786/175679) which contains an example code snippet.

Comment: Thanks alot.. in my answer I found similar way..
Does it mean that the mailboxes with "olExchangeMailbox" Type are Additional Mailboxes?

Comment: There are different `Store` types (see [`ExchangeStoreType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb208080%28v=office.12%29.aspx)). `olExchangeMailbox` is a shared Exchange mailbox.

Comment: I would like to backup those information using c# code and restore it again in my application. is it possible? 
I tried to serialize store objects however store class is not serializiable.